# problem with open a .xlxs file, someone else is using it

Tags: excel, vba, permissions, file-permissions, readfile

i have a problem when i try to open a file .xlxs in a public disk P: with VBA Code. The file show me a message "please try again later - ERROR 1004". Many user use this file and this error is frequently usual. There is a solution for this ?

I think in copy the file and paste to my desktop but that is a lot of wasted time because is a large file.

`Workbooks.Open filename:=nameofmyfile, Notify:=True, ReadOnly:=True`

[image]

Comment: Do a loop to continue trying to open the file.

Comment: Honestly, Excel is not a good front end program. If many users are expected to simultaneously use and update a file, any kind of database solution is going to be better suited (even if it's as simple as using MS Access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below and let us know if it works.

Use shared workbooks with different versions of Excel

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/use-shared-workbook

Comment: when somebody is using the file, the name of the file use this symbols "∼$".  I modified my code and i search a the second old file and that symbols no disturb my code.